# Reference for rigorous interacting many-body quantum mechanics

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-physics

Are there good references for (both zero and finite time) interacting systems of quantum many-body theory? More precisely, I would be interested in references discussing the following topics:

1. Second quantization
2. Zero and finite time Green's function (time-ordered two point function) and its relation to spectra of the full Hamiltonian (i.e. with interacting term)
3. Perturbation theory (e.g. [Gellmann and Low formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_and_Low_theorem), Wick's theorem etc)
4. Linear response theory

These are some standard topics in physics books about many-body quantum mechanics. I am basically looking for rigorous justification of (at least some) of the most important formulas in the physics textbooks about these topics using good functional analysis.

**Disclaimer:** I don't know to what degree the topics above are well-developed from the mathematical point of view. I am assuming one can get pretty far and cover a lot (if not every) topic using functional analysis and related techniques, in the spirit of Reed & Simon.

Answer (score 5):

A textbook that covers much ground in a mathematically rigorous way is [Mathematical Methods of Many-Body Quantum Field Theory](https://books.google.nl/books/about/Mathematical_Methods_of_Many_Body_Quantu.html?id=gWuLRTtdRFQC&redir_esc=y) by Detlef Lehmann (2004).

> This book offers a comprehensive, mathematically rigorous treatment of
> many-body physics. It develops the mathematical tools for describing
> quantum many-body systems and applies them to the many-electron
> system. These tools include the formalism of second quantization,
> field theoretical perturbation theory, functional integral methods,
> bosonic and fermionic, and estimation and summation techniques for
> Feynman diagrams.

Answer (score 3):

I believe all of these topics and more are also covered in

> *Dereziński, Jan; Gérard, Christian*, [**Mathematics of quantization and quantum fields**](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511894541.001), Cambridge Monographs on Mathematical Physics. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 978-1-107-01111-3/hbk; 978-0-511-89454-1/ebook). xii, 674 p. (2013). [ZBL1271.81004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1271.81004).